# Enable scrolling only for one section in UITableView

Tags: iphone

I have a two sections in my table view. First contains two rows, and second much more.
I need scrolling only for second section. Is it possible?

Comment: add scrollview as a subview to the section It May Work You have to use the custom tableview cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A table view is just *one big thing*.

If you want to have the first section static on-screen, you might want to put it outside of a table view after all, or split your table view into two separate table views.